# About Function Manipulation

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-programming

I have a function as follows (updated after the clarification question):

$$\max_{x∈X}\left(\sum\sum c_{ij}x_{ij}-\max_{y∈Y}\sum\sum d_{ij}x_{ij}y_{ij}\right)$$ where

- $x_{ij},y_{ij}$ are decision variables.
- $c_{ij}, d_{ij}$ are cost coefficients.

My question is, is it possible to disregard the minus in between and write it as follows?

$$\max_{x∈X,y∈Y}\left(\sum\sum c_{ij}x_{ij}+\sum\sum d_{ij}x_{ij}y_{ij}\right)$$

If it was a plus sign in the first place instead of minus, I know that we could have written as such. But for this case, I would like to clarify it.

Comment: Your original objective function needs clarification. Are you maximizing the difference between the first sum and maximum with respect to $y$ of the second sum, i.e., $\max_{x\in X} \left( \sum_{i,j} c_{ij}x_{ij} - \max_{y\in Y} \sum_{i,j} d_{ij}x_{ij} y_{ij}\right)?$

Comment: Thanks for your question! Yes, that is the case. However, if possible, I would love to learn how we treat the other cases too.

Comment: What other cases?

Comment: For instance this maybe: $Max_{x∈X}($$\sum\sum c_{ij}x_{ij}$$-Max_{x∈X,y∈Y} $$\sum\sum d_{ij}x_{ij}y_{ij}$)

Comment: Since $x$ is free to take different values in the first and second summations, that just splits into two problems: maximizing the first term over $x;$ then maximizing the second term over $x$ and $y.$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you cannot change the objective to maximizing a sum, not even if $d_{ij}$ in the second version is different from $d_{ij}$ in the first version. In the first version, for given $x$ you are choosing the $y\in Y$ that is *worst* for the overall objective value. In the second version, for given $x$ you are choosing the $y\in Y$ that is *best* for the overall objective value.

**Addendum**: Given the information that $x$ is integer and $y$ is continuous, and assuming that $Y$ and the convex hull of $X$ are polyhedral, the problem is solvable using a variant of Benders decomposition.

The master problem is \begin{align*}
\max & \sum_{i,j}c_{ij}x_{ij}-z\\
\textrm{s.t. }x & \in X\\
 & \cdots
\end{align*}
where $z$ is a surrogate for the inner maximization value and $\cdots$ is a placeholder for linear constraints to come. Given a candidate solution $(\bar{x},\bar{z})$ to the master problem, you solve the LP subproblem $$\max_{y\in Y} \sum_{i,j} (d_{ij}\bar{x}_{ij})y_{ij}$$
obtaining solution $\bar{y}$ with objective value $v.$ If $\bar{z}\ge v,$ accept $(\bar{x},\bar{z})$ as a new incumbent in the master. If not, add to the master the constraint $$z\ge \sum_{i,j}(d_{ij}\bar{y}_{ij})x_{ij},$$ which is linear in $x$ and $z$ and valid for all $x\in X.$

Comment: Do you think the first version has something to do with bilevel optimization? Also, is there any resource do you know of that I could use to study this concept further?

Comment: The first version is a form of "maximin" problem. You can rewrite it as $\max_x \min_y \sum_{i,j} \left( c_{ij}x_{ij} - d_{ij}x_{ij}y_{ij}\right).$ It is more common for people to refer to these as "minimax" problems, and you can find related questions here by looking for the "minimax" tag: https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minimax.

Comment: Do you think it is possible to write the first model as a single objective model? I think if we had $$\max_{x∈X,y∈Y}\min_{x∈X,y∈Y}\sum\sum c_{ij}x_{ij}-\sum\sum d_{ij}x_{ij}y_{ij}$$It would be possible by taking the objective to constraints like this: $$max(w:w\leq\sum\sum c_{ij}x_{ij}-\sum\sum d_{ij}x_{ij}y_{ij})$$But for this case: $$\max_{x∈X}(\sum\sum c_{ij}x_{ij}-\max_{y∈Y}\sum\sum d_{ij}x_{ij}y_{ij})$$I have been struggling as minimization is a subproblem here. @prubin

Comment: Your constraint would not work, because it allows the solver to choose the largest value for $w$ such that *some* feasible combination of $x$ and $y$ makes the right side larger. What you need is that *every* feasible combination makes the right side larger.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! Could you please elaborate further? Do you think it may not be possible to write the first model as a single objective problem in this way? If yes, can you think of any other way to solve it? I know that we can solve it by taking the minimization term's dual (Bertsimas and Sim, "Robust discrete optimization and network flows", 2003), but I am trying to generate other possible ways in order to better understand the model. @prubin

Comment: Do I think you can find a single objective that will work? No (but I might be wrong). Can I think of a way to solve it? Yes, but whether it is practical depends on $X$ and $Y$. Are they polyhedral? Are any of the variables integer-valued?

Comment: Yes, $X$ is integer-valued, $Y$ is continuous.

Comment: I added a possible solution method to my answer.